# How to target document.body.appendchild(' to root document not iframe

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How do we target 
`document.body.appendchild(' an element ')` into the root document only and get avoided going into an iframe
I did such as

```
var a=document.createElement('a')
document.body.appendchild(a)
```

just found it on

> iframe>#document>html>body>a

Sincere help is gratified

Comment: Sounds like `document` refers to the document inside the iframe. If you never declared `document`, then your Javascript context already starts out inside the iframe, and you'll need to escape it somehow

Answer (score 0):

If you call this from inside iframe, then you need to use this code (also appendChild require Node as argument it can't be string):

```
var a = parent.document.createElement('p');
a.innerHTML = 'hello';
parent.document.documentElement.appendChild(a);
// or
parent.document.body.appendChild(a);
```

parent to get window object of document where iframe is located, then get document and then actual DOM node (`documentElement` will be html element).

**NOTE:** the iframe and parent document need to be on same domain because of Same Origin Policy. If you want to use documents on different domains you need to be in control for both of them and use postMessage or similar API to send message from iframe and get it on parent document.

Comment: Not work on Chrome content script put after onload=function(){...  Don't know on other circumstances.
the tested page is https://catchvideo.net/

Comment: @yaasiin are you sure this the right site? It's just some download video public service with lot of JS code inside.

Comment: the codes must be on Chrome content-script extension put after onload=function(){.. to evade the iframe. the extension must be completely applicable universally to any page, the page above is just one sample that's unexpectedly found being stumble-block. The script is doing screen filter but going to have multi features added in the future, that's it here doing zoom if user hover at anchor element injected,  at line 63 of https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UatnRKzWHNm00VEio9YhvER5q8xfNg0W
the addon: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/soft-screen/oecaicengbgemdbdklmajocogdjjgnda

Comment: @yaasiin I'm not sure if you will be able to use this as user script, to access cross-origin iframe you need special privileges (maybe real chrome extension that will get permission), I think that user script is the same as normal JavaScript added with script tag  to your page. Unless the script runs on both pages parent and iframe child then you can use postMessage to communicate between the two.